# Can't connect to Azure using a VPN client to Rackspace through a Site to Site VPN with Rackspace and Azure

Tags: networking, azure, vpn, rackspace

We have a site to site vpn setup between rackspace and azure. When I'm inside the rackspace network (ie remote desktop onto a rackspace server) I have no trouble connecting to our azure vms. However, when I connect to rackspace using a vpn client I don't get the same behavior.

Rackspace have told me that packets are getting passed through but nothing is getting returned. They're telling me it's down to the vpn firewall configuration on the azure side. I've added our ip ranges under the local network section in azure.

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated.

As a bit of background the only reason we're going this route is because we can't vpn directly into azure (don't want to use connect as we want to do it at our router level) and we don't have an external ip so we can't use a site to site vpn form the office.

Any input really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The azure team are providing direct support

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork/thread/75c87385-fefc-4edc-876d-4be577986a27